# Swap array keys position

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, swap

I need to swap the array keys 
This is what I have

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => file1.pdf
    [1] => file2.pdf
    [2] => file3.pdf
    [3] => file4.pdf
    [4] => file5.pdf
    [5] => file6.pdf
  )
```

And this is what I need

```
  Array
  (
    [1] => file2.pdf
    [0] => file1.pdf
    [3] => file4.pdf
    [2] => file3.pdf
    [5] => file6.pdf
    [4] => file5.pdf
  )
```

I don't know how big the array is, but the array is always even.
Can somebody help me with this problem.

Comment: ...........why?

Comment: I have pages that needs to be sent to print in that order

Comment: Why do you need to keep the indexes the same then?

Comment: Create a new array, add data to it in the specific order and use it. It's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it, hope it will help.

First we create new array, which we put new ordered data into. Next we will iterate through our old array and put custom data to $newArr.

```
<?php

$arr = array("file1.pdf", "file2.pdf", "file3.pdf", "file4.pdf", "file5.pdf", "file6.pdf");
$newArr = [];

$a = 0;
$arrCount = count($arr);

while (count($newArr) !== $arrCount) {
    $newArr[$a + 1] = $arr[$a + 1];
    $newArr[$a] = $arr[$a];
    $a = $a  +  2;
}

// Old array
print_r($arr);

// New array
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array=Array
  (
    "file1.pdf",
    "file2.pdf",
    "file3.pdf",
    "file4.pdf",
    "file5.pdf",
    "file6.pdf"
  );
  $newarray=[];
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if($key & 1){
        $newarray[]=$array[$key];
        $newarray[]=$array[$key-1];
      }
  }
  array_push($newarray,$array[count($array)-1];
  $newarray=array_unique($newarray);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($newarray);
  echo "</pre>";
  ?>
```